# Retrieve uncommon columns with the help of common columns in a table

Tags: sql, join

How to retrieve uncommon columns with the help of common columns in a table in SQL (based on common columns orderid & orderamt need result as comparison

Example
Raw data

```
SellerID    CustID  OrderID OrderAmt
1251        197     1675    2515
1259        201     1971    5135
1271        199     1675    2515
1299        197     1971    5135
1289        211     1972    5135
```

Result

```
OrderID OrderAmt    SellerID    CustID  SellerID1   CustID1
1675    2515        1251        197     1271        199
1971    5135        1259        201     1299        197
```

Comment: You seem to be wanting to group your raw data based on `OrderID` & `OrderAmt` and aggregating `CustID` and `SellerId`.  Please explain further what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Self-join the table on common columns and filter by uncommon ones:

```
Select
  a.OrderID, a.OrderAmt,
  a.SellerID, a.CustID,
  b.SellerID As SellerID1, b.CustID As CustID1
From
  [SourceTable] a
Inner Join
  [SourceTable] b
On
  a.OrderID = b.OrderID AND a.OrderAmt = b.OrderAmt
Where
  a.SellerID <> b.SellerID OR a.CustID <> b.CustID
```